# MOQ IConfiguration with specific parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mstest, autofixture

Today I was writing a unit test for one of my class which has a parameter of [IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.0) in the constructor. I tried to freeze dependency and create sut.

```
 configuration = builders.Freeze<IConfiguration>();
 apiConfiguration = builders.Create<IAPIConfiguration>();
```

When I ran the test I got an exception because in API configuration constructor I have validation line.

```
 this.API_KEY = configuration["API:Key"] ?? throw new NoNullAllowedException("API key wasn't found.");
```

It seems that it didn't mock the right way or at least the way I wanted. 
I start to wonder is there any way to mock out IConfiguration class with customizable keys?

**UPDATED:**

SUT:

```
public class APIConfiguration : IAPIConfiguration
    {
        public APIConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.API_KEY = configuration["API:Key"] ?? throw new NoNullAllowedException("API key wasn't found.");
            this._url = configuration["API:URL"] ?? throw new NoNullAllowedException("API key wasn't found.");
        }

        public string API_KEY { get; }

        private string _url
        {
            get { return this._url; }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    throw new NoNullAllowedException("API url wasn't found.");
                this._url = value;
            }
        }

        public Uri URL
        {
            get
            {
                return this.URL;
            }
            private set
            {
                value = new Uri(this._url);
            }
        }
    }
```

Test case so far:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {

        private readonly IFixture builders;
        private readonly string _apiKey;
        private readonly string _url;
        private readonly IAPIConfiguration apiConfiguration;
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public UnitTest1()
        {
            builders = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
            _apiKey = builders.Create<string>();
            _url = builders.Create<string>();
            configuration = builders.Freeze<IConfiguration>();
            configuration["API:Key"] = "testKey";
            configuration["API:URL"] = "testUrl";

            apiConfiguration = builders.Build<IAPIConfiguration>().Create();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreSame(configuration["API:Key"], apiConfiguration.API_KEY);
        }
    }
```

Test brakes in the constructor of the test on line

```
apiConfiguration = builders.Build<IAPIConfiguration>().Create();
```

Comment: Did you configure the mock to behave as expected when invoked?

Comment: @Nkosi, Yes, I have this line before any other code builders = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

Comment: All that does is create a mock. It does nothing in configuring the mock's behavior

Comment: @Nkosi, you mean something like this configuration["API:Key"] = "testKey"; ? Could you provide an example of configuring mock's behavior because, I guess, I'm not sure what you talking about?

Comment: Show the subject class under test and the test as it is so far

Comment: @Nkosi, I updated my question

Comment: checking it now

Comment: Testing it and fixed the fixture issue. However I have discovered a stackoverflow exception in your _url property as it is calling and setting itself.

Comment: @Nkosi, I know this issue. It is temporary I'll fix it later. What was the problem, or better to say what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that does is create a mock. It does nothing in configuring the mock's behavior.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {
    //Arrange
    //Freeze-Build-Create sequence
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var apiKey = fixture.Create<string>();
    var url = "http://example.com";
    var configuration = fixture.Freeze<IConfiguration>();

    //Configure the expected behavior of the mock
    var keys = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "API:Key" , apiKey },
        { "API:URL", url }
    };
    var mock = Mock.Get(configuration);
    mock.Setup(_ => _[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns((string key) => keys[key]);

    IAPIConfiguration apiConfiguration = fixture.Build<APIConfiguration>().Create();

    //Act
    var actual = apiConfiguration.API_KEY;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(apiKey, actual);
    Assert.AreEqual(new Uri(url), apiConfiguration.URL);
}
```

The above extracts the mock from the fixture and configures the expected behavior for the test case.

The test also exposed issues with the subject under test which had to be refactored to

```
public class APIConfiguration : IAPIConfiguration {
    public APIConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration) {
        this.API_KEY = configuration["API:Key"] ?? throw new NoNullAllowedException("API key wasn't found.");
        this._url = configuration["API:URL"] ?? throw new NoNullAllowedException("API url wasn't found.");
    }

    public string API_KEY { get; }

    private string _url;

    public Uri URL {
        get {
            return new Uri(this._url);
        }
    }
}
```

to fix issues related to its original design.

Comment: it strange, but I still getting API key wasn't found. Did it work for you?

Comment: The code I posted is actual code I used to test and it worked. That is how I was able to find your stack overflow error and the URL error

Comment: yes. It works. Sorry for the confusion. Visual Studio didn't work correctly. Now everything is ok. Thanks!